# W2VTransformer: Only works with one word as input?

Tags: scikit-learn, gensim, word2vec

Following reproducible script is used to compute the accuracy of a Word2Vec classifier with the `W2VTransformer` wrapper in gensim:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from gensim.sklearn_api import W2VTransformer
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

# Load synthetic data
data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/EPCmabvN')
data = data.head(10)

# Set random seed
np.random.seed(0)

# Tokenize text
X_train = data.apply(lambda r: simple_preprocess(r['text'], min_len=2), axis=1)
# Get labels
y_train = data.label

train_input = [x[0] for x in X_train]

# Train W2V Model
model = W2VTransformer(size=10, min_count=1)
model.fit(X_train)

clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=0.1)
clf.fit(model.transform(train_input), y_train)

text_w2v = Pipeline(
    [('features', model),
     ('classifier', clf)])

score = text_w2v.score(train_input, y_train)
score
```

> 0.80000000000000004

The problem with this script is that it **only** works when `train_input = [x[0] for x in X_train]`, which essentially is always the first word only. 
Once change to `train_input = X_train` (or `train_input` simply substituted by `X_train`), the script returns:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (10,10)

How can I solve this issue, i.e. how can the classifier work with more than one word of input?

**Edit:**

Apparently, the W2V wrapper can't work with the variable-length train input, as compared to D2V. Here is a working D2V version:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess, lemmatize
from gensim.sklearn_api import D2VTransformer

data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/bSGWiBfs')

np.random.seed(0)

X_train = data.apply(lambda r: simple_preprocess(r['text'], min_len=2), axis=1)
y_train = data.label

model = D2VTransformer(dm=1, size=50, min_count=2, iter=10, seed=0)
model.fit(X_train)

clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=0.1, random_state=0)
clf.fit(model.transform(X_train), y_train)

pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('vec', model),
        ('clf', clf)
    ])

y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_train)
score = accuracy_score(y_train,y_pred)
print(score)
```

Comment: **Where** does the script return that `ValueError`? (It's much easier to see what's going wrong if you can show the full error stack, so you should edit the question to include that extra level of detail.)

Comment: **re: your update** Yes, the `W2VTransformer` does not collapse a variable-length list-of-words to a single vector, as that's not an automatically-desirable capability of the wrapped `Word2Vec` model. Instead, it converts a variable-length list-of-words to a same-length list-of-vectors. If you need to collapse those to a single vector for later steps, you could implement that as a following transformer, perhaps one that averages all the vectors together. (That often works as a simple baseline approach, though other weightings or algorithms might work better depending on your data & goals.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is technically not an answer, but cannot be written in comments so here it is. There are multiple issues here:

- `LogisticRegression` class (and most other scikit-learn models) work with 2-d data `(n_samples, n_features)`.

  That means that it needs a collection of 1-d arrays (one for each row (sample), in which the elements of array contains the feature values).

  In your data, a single word will be a 1-d array, which means that the single sentence (sample) will be a 2-d array. Which means that the complete data (collection of sentences here) will be a collection of 2-d arrays. Even in that, since each sentence can have different number of words, it cannot be combined into a single 3-d array.
- Secondly, the `W2VTransformer` in gensim looks like a scikit-learn compatible class, but its not. It tries to follows "scikit-learn API conventions" for defining the methods `fit()`, `fit_transform()` and `transform()`. They are **not compatible** with scikit-learn `Pipeline`.

  You can see that the input param requirements of `fit()` and `fit_transform()` are different.

  - [`fit()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/sklearn_api/w2vmodel.html#gensim.sklearn_api.w2vmodel.W2VTransformer.fit):

    > **X (iterable of iterables of str)** – The input corpus.
    >
    > X can be simply a list of lists of tokens, but for larger corpora, consider an iterable that streams the sentences directly from
    >   disk/network. See BrownCorpus, Text8Corpus or LineSentence in word2vec
    >   module for such examples.
  - [`fit_transform()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/sklearn_api/w2vmodel.html#gensim.sklearn_api.w2vmodel.W2VTransformer.fit_transform):

    > **X (numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features])** – Training set.

If you want to use scikit-learn, then you will need to have the 2-d shape. You will need to "somehow merge" word-vectors for a single sentence to form a 1-d array for that sentence. That means that you need to form a kind of sentence-vector, by doing:

- sum of individual words
- average of individual words
- weighted averaging of individual words based on frequency, tf-idf etc.
- using other techniques like sent2vec, paragraph2vec, doc2vec etc.

**Note**:- I noticed now that [you were doing this thing based on `D2VTransformer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997148/implementing-gensim-wrapper-into-sklearn). That should be the correct approach here if you want to use sklearn.

The issue in that question was this line (since that question is now deleted):

```
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Here, you overwrite your original `X_train` (list of list of words) with already calculated word vectors and hence that error.

Or else, you can use other tools / libraries (keras, tensorflow) which allow sequential input of variable size. For example, LSTMs can be configured here to take a variable input and an ending token to mark the end of sentence (a sample).

**Update**:

In the above given solution, you can replace the lines:

```
model = D2VTransformer(dm=1, size=50, min_count=2, iter=10, seed=0)
model.fit(X_train)

clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=0.1, random_state=0)
clf.fit(model.transform(X_train), y_train)

pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('vec', model),
        ('clf', clf)
    ])

y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_train)
```

with

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('vec', model),
        ('clf', clf)
    ])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_train)
```

No need to fit and transform separately, since `pipeline.fit()` will automatically do that.

Comment: Yes, apparently the D2V version seems to work.. I also added a working version above. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Christopher I have updated the answer with the error in that question.

Comment: Where exact? It seems to work. I think `model.transform(X_train)`solved it?

Comment: @Christopher The error about `"ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with ..."`. It will happen when you combine both the codes active (`D2V Example - Without Pipeline` and `D2V Example - With Pipeline`). In that case, the `X_train` that gets passed to pipeline is already doc vectors. If you remove the without pipeline example and its code, then X_train is Series of words.

Comment: I think you relate to another post, right? The D2V example above seems to work just fine? I only wondered why W2V did not work.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, I mentioned in the update that its about other post. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I deleted it because it was indeed confusing :) Can you confirm the D2V solution above is correct?

Comment: @Christopher Yes its correct. I have updated it slightly for better code.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I did not know it would do that automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186040/discussion-between-christopher-and-vivek-kumar).